# Source Code for gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

Where can I get the source code for gdal_translate? I need to modify it for my own use.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdal_translate_bin.cpp

you can also check with the gdal-dev mailing list to help you with its business logic.